# How can I auto add everyone in my organization each time I create a new board?

Tags: trello

I have a team of 10-12 users that are all using Trello. Every time I create a new board I have to manually invite all of them to participate on the new board. Is there a way to default all users in my organization to be assigned to the board when it is created?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you want to create what Trello calls an "organization".

You can get to it by clicking on your picture in the top right and selecting Boards, then at the bottom [Create an Organization](https://trello.com/org/create).

Then when you create a new board, you can set the permissions so your entire organization can see it.

Comment: ... of course, if you specific members of your org to be able to add/edit cards, then you'll need to add them as board members.

Comment: @Michael: Is it a planned feature to enable similarly fast configuration to let an entire organization add/edit (e.g. become members)?

Comment: @DanielLeCheminant Seems like an oft-requested feature.

Comment: Card for a the "better way to invite an org to a board" feature: https://trello.com/card/board/button-to-invite-all-org-members-to-a-board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e863e8b7c30b184f69bf9a3