# Simpler board member management within organization

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I auto add everyone in my organization each time I create a new board?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19020/how-can-i-auto-add-everyone-in-my-organization-each-time-i-create-a-new-board)

How can I assign members to boards within an organization without sending an email invite? We already have several boards, and my team is getting overwhelmed/irritated by invitation emails.